# Getting "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli' when trying to run "ng serve"

Tags: angular-cli, angular-compiler-cli

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/axbtO.png

Getting `"An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'` when trying to run "`ng serve`"

> Error I am getting

```
PS D:\Study\PoolCarz> ng serve
An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
Require stack:
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\typescript.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\index.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\package-chunk-sort.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\browser\index.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\node-modules-architect-host.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\node\index.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\serve-impl.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\export-ref.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular-devkit\schematics\tools\index.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular\cli\utilities\json-schema.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command-runner.js
- D:\Study\PoolCarz\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\cli\index.js
- C:\Users\smriti.bhawana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\lib\init.js
- C:\Users\smriti.bhawana\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
See "C:\Users\SMRITI~1.BHA\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-CvHKUy\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

> Package.json file contain below:

```
  {
              "name": "pool-carz",
              "version": "0.0.0",
              "scripts": {
                "ng": "ng",
                "start": "ng serve",
                "build": "ng build",
                "test": "ng test",
                "lint": "ng lint",
                "e2e": "ng e2e"
              },
              "private": true,
              "dependencies": {
                "@angular/animations": "~11.2.3",
                "@angular/common": "~11.2.3",
                "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.3",
                "@angular/core": "~11.2.3",
                "@angular/forms": "~11.2.3",
                "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.3",
                "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.3",
                "@angular/router": "~11.2.3",
                "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
                "tslib": "^2.0.0",
                "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
              },
              "devDependencies": {
                "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1101.4",
                "@angular/cli": "^11.2.2",
                "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.3",
                "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
                "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
                "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
                "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
                "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
                "karma": "~5.2.0",
                "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
                "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
                "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
                "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
                "protractor": "~7.0.0",
                "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
                "tslint": "~6.1.0",
                "typescript": "^4.1.5"
              }
            }
```

> ng version

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.2
Node: 14.15.5      
OS: win32 x64      

Angular: 11.1.2
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1101.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1101.4
@angular-devkit/core            11.1.4
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.2
@angular/cli                    11.2.2
@angular/compiler-cli           <error>
@schematics/angular             11.2.2
@schematics/update              0.1102.2
rxjs                            6.6.6
typescript                      4.1.5
```

> npm version

```
{
  'pool-carz': '0.0.0',
  npm: '6.14.11',
  ares: '1.16.1',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  cldr: '37.0',
  icu: '67.1',
  llhttp: '2.1.3',
  modules: '83',
  napi: '7',
  nghttp2: '1.41.0',
  node: '14.15.5',
  openssl: '1.1.1i',
  tz: '2020a',
  unicode: '13.0',
  uv: '1.40.0',
  v8: '8.4.371.19-node.18',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try re-installing all your modules.

1. Delete your **node_modules** folder manually or by running `rm -r node_modules`.
2. Clear npm's cache: `npm cache clean --force`.
3. `npm install`.

Comment: What if you first remove `package-lock.json` file then try these steps?

Answer (score 0):

When `npm install` was not installing all dev dependencies for me automatically.
I tried running bellow script for each dev dependencies one by one:

```
npm i --save-dev @angular/animations
npm i --save-dev @angular/cli
npm i --save-dev @angular/common
npm i --save-dev @angular/compiler
npm i --save-dev @angular/compiler-cli
npm i --save-dev @angular/core
npm i --save-dev @angular/forms
npm i --save-dev @angular/language-service
npm i --save-dev @angular/platform-browser
npm i --save-dev @angular/platform-browser-dynamic
npm i --save-dev @angular/router
```

and then `ng serve` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :-

1. Delete `node_modules` folder.
2. Then clean cache by this command: `npm cache clean --force`
3. run `npm i`
4. And now run `ng s`. It worked for me.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 x64 version and working on VScode.

My error was this in image but after following these steps, `ng s` worked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adMiU.png)